# Git Notification of Untracked and Changes files before initial commit

Tags: python, git, github

I have a project which contains multiple packages, `package_a/` and `package_b/`. Each package contains a class or two in appropriate sub-directories. I am okay with both of these packages existing on the master branch. However, I run into trouble when I do the following procedure:

I added, committed and pushed `package_a/` to the master branch. This was pushed upstream (I believe that is the term) when I pushed by entering `git push -u origin master` during my push. This is reflected when I log into my github account. Everything is great so far.

I add package_b/. After adding package_b/ but before committing and pushing it, I enter the directory and see a bunch of files that were added, which is to be expected since it contains sub-directories containing classes, and an **init**.py file. However, I also see a sub-directory that has modified content, hence the changes were not staged for commit.

Essentially:

```
        new file:    package_b/__init__.py
        new file:    package_b/class_b

Changes not staged for commit:

        modified:    package_b/class_b
```

How can there be modified content since I have not yet committed anything in package_b? package_a does not import anything from package_b and vice versa, in case that is relevant.

Very new to git here and trying to establish good practices early. I appreciate the feedback!

Git appears as the following:

```
Peter Altamura@AltamuraDesktop MINGW64 /f/liteSaber (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        containers/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Peter Altamura@AltamuraDesktop MINGW64 /f/liteSaber (master)
$ git checkout -b gd_api
Switched to a new branch 'gd_api'

Peter Altamura@AltamuraDesktop MINGW64 /f/liteSaber (gd_api)
$ git add containers/

Peter Altamura@AltamuraDesktop MINGW64 /f/liteSaber (gd_api)
$ git status
On branch gd_api
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   containers/__init__.py
        new file:   containers/base_obj.py
        new file:   containers/game/__init__.py
        new file:   containers/game/game.py
        new file:   containers/gameday
        new file:   containers/player/__init__.py
        new file:   containers/player/player.py
        new file:   containers/player/team.py
        new file:   containers/toolkit/__init__.py
        new file:   containers/toolkit/reference.py
        new file:   containers/toolkit/tools.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   containers/gameday (modified content, untracked content)
```

> $ find -name .git
>
> ./.git
>
> ./containers/.git
>
> ./containers/gameday/.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `git status` is showing you are the changes between what is in your local directory and what you have staged. So it looks like added `class_b` to the index with `git add` (but did not commit), and then changed `class_b` in some way. So what this is telling you is that if you run `git commit`, only the contents of `class_b` at the time you called `git add` will be committed.

Keep in mind that `git add` is not just for adding new files to the repo, but also for adding *changes* to an existing file to the repo (or more accurately, overwriting the existing file in the index with you local copy). It is not the best named command, given what it does.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What confuses me though is I did not change `class_b` after adding. I brought the sub directory and its files into my repo as entirely new files, `git add class_b/`, then did `git status`. They were never even open during this process, so I certainly did not change them in between these steps.

Comment: @Alt182 - is `class_b` a file or a directory?

Comment: `class_b` is a directory containing two files, `__init__.py` and `game.py` where `game.py` contains the actual definition of the class.

Comment: @Alt182, hmm, something seems off here. Git tracks files, not directories. Could you put the exact output of `git status` in your question?

Comment: Added to question. I had other things going and I just showed the same thing happening when I tried to add a branch and add `container/` there instead. `container/` contains classes in sub-directories

Comment: I'm thinking `class_b` might be a submodule,  a nested repository.  `git status` has this habit of referring to those as "files".  Do `find -name .git`.

Comment: Ah, good catch @jthill. That might be it. This was really baffling me!

Comment: Posted the find -name .git in the original. Still getting acquainted with formatting properly. Greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: @Alt182 I was under the impression that these were new directories you were adding; where did `.git` directories come from? Did you get these from an existing repo, or run `git init` multiple times or something?

Comment: I can confirm I ran git init once, however these files were part of an old repo, but that repo was removed in its entirety before this current repo was created. I thought that would disassociate the files as being an "existing repo" but perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @Alt182 So if you are cool with losing the history of the old repo, I would just remove all the `.git` directories, remove everything from the (new) server repo with `git push :master`, and start over with a single `git init` in the root directory. Then you can add everything without messing with submodules and whatnot.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Im not married to the history whatsoever. I care more that its done clean than having this history. I appreciate the help. Thanks again.